# Python NLTK align import error

Tags: python, nltk, python-import, python-module

I am getting a strange import error for NLTK's align module:

```
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.10
$ pip2 freeze | grep nltk
nltk==3.2
$ python2
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.align import AlignedSent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named align
```

As you can see, I have nltk 3.2 installed for python 2.7. I can import `nltk` directly. However, I cannot access the `align` module.

I know the import statement I used is correct, since I took it directly from [the official documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.align.html). Additionally, I looked at [the interface changes from NLTK 2 to NLTK 3](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Porting-your-code-to-NLTK-3.0) and there is no mention there of the `align` module.

---

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of NLTK version 3.2, the `align` module has been [renamed to `translate`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/commit/7690cbf5f4b548b51d1985c6432dade3d09bb460). Therefore use:

```
from nltk.translate import AlignedSent
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me

Comment: OK, but how comes that the examples in NLTK 3.5b1 documentation still use `from nltk.align import AlignedSent` ?  I have installed NLTK 3.4.5 and I keep meetting examples in "HOWTO" section of  that documentation that don't work. Do you know how to cope with this problem?